# How to dynamically change an object value without adding a lot of redundant code?

Tags: jquery, object, cookies

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this. I've got a jquery object that sets a cookie.

But the problem is there are certain instances when I want the cookie name to be something different from `user-height`. For instance, I want the cookie name to be `user-weight`.

Is there a way to somehow change the cookie name or set a fallback without having a bunch of redundant code?

```
var height_cookie = {
    name: 'user-height',
    options: {
        path: '/',
        expires: 365
    }
};

function userHeightCookie() {
        var userData = $.parseJSON($.cookie(height_cookie.name));
        return(userData);
};

function readHeightCookie(userInfo) {
    $.cookie(height_cookie.name, JSON.stringify(userInfo), height_cookie.options);
};

function deleteHeightCookie() { $.cookie(height_cookie.name, null, height_cookie.options); }
```

Comment: I think you should get it, save it with another name and delete the old one

Comment: This might come off as a bit overbearing, but an Object-Oriented approach would serve you greatly here and in general.

Comment: Would either of you guys have a code snippet for your suggestions? Kind of a newb and I learn best by seeing examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A little about OOP**

What you are basically looking to do is to generalize your code, so you'll be able to efficiently reuse its different parts, without having to repeat the same code over and over. This is where object-oriented-programming or OOP comes in. At the risk of oversimplifying, it is a very powerful and useful programming approach that allows you to effectively compartmentalize your logic. I highly recommend you read up a little (or more) on this subject, as it vastly exceeds the limits of this crude explanation and following example.

**A relevant example**

Consider the following object-oriented example based on your own:

```
 // Declare a class of cookies
var yummyCookie = function(cookieName, cookieOptions) {
    return {
         // Class attributes
        name: cookieName ? cookieName : 'user-height',
        options: cookieOptions ? cookieOptions : { path: '/', expires: 365 },

         // Class methods
        setCookieValue: function(userInfo) {
            $.cookie(this.name, JSON.stringify(userInfo), this.options);
        },
         //   
        getCookieValue: function() {
            return $.parseJSON($.cookie(this.name));
        },
         //                      
        resetCookie: function() {
            $.cookie(this.name, null, this.options);    
        }
    }
}

 // Create instances of the class
var heightCookie = new yummyCookie('user-height');
var weightCookie = new yummyCookie('user-weight');

 // Set, get and reset the height cookie
heightCookie.setCookieValue('175');
alert(heightCookie.getCookieValue());
heightCookie.resetCookieValue();

 // Set, get and reset the weight cookie
weightCookie.setCookieValue('65');
alert(weightCookie.getCookieValue());
weightCookie.resetCookieValue();
```

Note how the class attributes accept custom values but also have default settings in case no values are passed to the object constructor function. For example, based on your logic, `new yummyCookie()` is equivalent to `new yummyCookie('user-height')`.